# MySQL failed server installation 8.0.19

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn MySQL and am encountering installation errors.

[server installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzvtd.png)

Comment: Where's the error or log message?

Comment: I uninstalled and am trying to use 64 bit version.  requires option file or something.  the message log was like 10000 lines so I'm not sure it would have been useful.

Comment: What was the required option file(s)? Have you not installed it or did you opt not to install it?

Comment: i figured it out.